# cursor: pointer not working in mac safari in ::before without anchor tag

Tags: jquery, css

I am using cursor:pointer to show hand when mouse over on light-grey box inside in dark-grey box by using check::before css, its working fine in chrome but not in mac safari. I don't want to use anchor tag for this. Below is my code:-

```css
div.check{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}
div.check::before{
    content: '';
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    top: 30%;
    z-index: 999999999;
    display: block;
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="check"></div>
```

Please suggestion me the solution.